# Proper solution to pick/click an image on Android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent, android-camera2

As the title suggests, i'm having an option to upload an image in my app.
I would like to have two options: Click a new picture & Select from gallery.
Gallery selection is working fine on all devices using this code:

```
Intent in = new Intent();
in.setType("image/*");
in.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(in, getString(R.string.selectpicture)), 100);
```

The problem is with `Click a new picture`.

I want to use other camera apps installed on the device to get the image.
This code should save the image user clicks at the specified path.

```
Intent m_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
imageUri = getImageUri();
m_intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
startActivityForResult(m_intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

But what happens is, the `EXTRA_OUTPUT` is not respected by all camera apps.

Also if memory is low, my app is killed by the system which makes things more complicated.

So, what's the best way to enable user to click a new picture and get the image path in my app? 
If using third party libraries is better, which one's are reliable?

Answer (score 2):

> the EXTRA_OUTPUT is not respected by all camera apps.

Any time you delegate anything to a third party app, you can run into problems.

> Also if memory is low, my app is killed by the system which makes things more complicated.

You need to handle this anyway. Save the value you put in `EXTRA_OUTPUT` in the saved instance state `Bundle`.

> what's the best way to enable user to click a new picture and get the image path in my app?

If you wish to stick with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, I'd go with this triage:

- If there is an image in the location you provided to `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, use it
- If not, and `getData()` on the `Intent` given to you in `onActivityResult()` returns a `Uri` (and not `null`), use that (and if you truly need a `File`, use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` with the `Uri` and copy the contents into your own file)
- If neither are true, and `getParcelableExtra("data")` returns a value, save that `Bitmap` to a file
- If none of those are true, suggest to the user to get a different camera app, perhaps pointing them to one that you have tried and know works

Or, take the picture yourself, directly or using a library like [mine](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2/issues).