# Android get path of latest taken photo

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I'm launching the camera from my app to take a photo. It also becomes available in the gallery.

The common issue with this, is how to know the path of the photo. The proposed solutions are:

1. save the path yourself, and send it over using `EXTRA_OUTPUT`
2. take the path from the last taken photo in the gallery.

Solution 1 [isn't reliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348757/mediastore-extra-output-renders-data-null-other-way-to-save-photos).

I'm trying to make solution 2 work, with this code:

```
public static String getTakenPhotoPath(Context context) {
    try {
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection, null, null, null);

        int column_index_data = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToLast();

        return cursor.getString(column_index_data);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();

        return null;
    }
}
```

This doesn't return the path of the latest photo; it returns the previous one. Before asking for the path of the latest photo, I'm doing this:

```
private void addToGallery(Uri urlType, String path) {
    if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(path)) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        // Add the date meta data to ensure the image is added at the front of the gallery
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis());
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, path);

        getContentResolver().insert(urlType, values);

        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Solution 2 is less reliable than Solution 1, by a wide margin. There is no requirement for a camera app to have the `MediaStore` index the image, let alone do so in a timely fashion. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41945392/115145) for my recommended `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` triage.

Comment: Solution 1 is reliable. I've never seen it fail.

Comment: @greenapps: You haven't seen all the people here on Stack Overflow reporting problems from various camera apps. `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` simply isn't tested much, and some developers don't read the documentation for how `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is supposed to work. See [this rant of mine from 2015](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/08/action-image-capture-fallacy.html) for more.

Comment: Why don't you just call your `Uri.getPath()` in `onActivityResult`

Comment: @CommonsWare isn't  `CWAC cam -2 ` a better choice?

Comment: @OBX: It is *a* choice. "Better" requires criteria, and there are plenty of criteria in which CWAC-Cam2 is not a better choice. For example, if a criterion is "must have been developed by people with full heads of hair", CWAC-Cam2 sucks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can it do like this: When you are opening the camera, you can pass your own preferred location for future captured image like this in given code. And in `onActivityResult` you can directly use that image path for your use.

```
 File image ;
    Intent photoCaptureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File imagesFolder = new    File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyImages");
            imagesFolder.mkdirs(); // <----
            image = new File(imagesFolder, getFileName());
            Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
            photoCaptureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
            startActivityForResult(photoCaptureIntent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);


    private String getFileName() {
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss");
            Date now = new Date();
            String fileName = formatter.format(now) + ".jpg";
            return fileName;
        }


@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        try {
            setResult(resultCode, data);


            switch (requestCode) {
                case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
                    try {
                        if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
                            Intent upload = new Intent(EditProfile.this, ImageCropingFucAtivity.class);
                            prefs.edit().putBoolean("FromCamera", true).commit();
                            upload.putExtra(CropImage.IMAGE_PATH, image.toString());
                            upload.putExtra(CropImage.SCALE, true);
                            upload.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_X, 2);
                            upload.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_Y, 2);
                            startActivity(upload);
                            imageSelected = true;
                            finish();
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    break;

                  }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Isn't that exactly his "solution 1"?

Comment: but it is solution for his query, And I am using this on my project it is working fine.